# Angular: resolve all route segments configuration by URL

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-router

Given a URL, e.g. `/path/path2/path3/123;sdf=df` and a routes configuration:

```
{ path: 'path', data: { g: 'h' }, children: [
  { path: 'path2', data: { c: 'd' }, children: [
    { path: 'something', component: TestpageComponent, data: { a: 'b' } },
    { path: 'path3/create', component: TestpageComponent, data: { b: 'c' } },
    { path: 'path3/:id', component: TestpageComponent, data: { b: 'c' } },
  ] }
] },
```

What I need is to find an actual configuration for all the segments in order to get a result set of all `data` parameters on all levels (each segment of the url).

I can split the URL in the segments by e.g.

```
console.log(this.router.parseUrl(url));
```

or to be more precise

```
console.log(this.router.parseUrl(url).root.children['primary'].segments);
```

which will return

```
[{"path":"path","parameters":{}},{"path":"path2","parameters":{}},{"path":"and","parameters":{}},{"path":"123","parameters":{"sdf":"df"}}]
```

So, splitting the URL into segments is not a problem. However I need to get a configuration for each segment.

I can get the actual configuration for all the routes with

```
console.log(this.router.config);
```

I can go with the segments through the configuration tree and find out the branch I need, but it can cause troubles e.g. while resolving `:id` against `create` segment. So, I would like to use the *router's* way of resolving the configuration that if the inner router implementation changes I would not need to change mine.

Example: imagine I have a 50% of the URLs protected by some guard (e.g. only logged in users could go there) and other 50% is not protected (displayed for everybody). So, on the navigation menu level (outside of the `router-outlet`) I want to display only the links which are relevant for the current user, so I need to know which routes are protected by the guard. Guards / data / whatever is just a particular case of the problem.

**Please do not stick to the example**, I am searching for a common way to get the configuration set for a particular URL.

Is this anyhow possible?

Comment: smnbbrv What url variable in your post? Where did you defined it? Please reply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With version 2.x you can use the `recognize` function the router internally uses to match an url to a `RouteStateSnapshot`.

```
import { recognize } from '@angular/router/src/recognize';

recognize(null, this.router.config, this.router.parseUrl(url), url).subscribe(route => {
    var routeSnapshot = route.root.firstChild;

    // Go to all children to get actual route.
    // If you use routes with children you should have
    // the full tree here
    var childSnapshot = routeSnapshot.firstChild;
    while (childSnapshot != null) {
        childSnapshot = routeSnapshot.firstChild;
        if (childSnapshot != null) {
            routeSnapshot = childSnapshot;
        }
    }

    let routeData = routeSnapshot.data || {};

    // routeData['a']...
});
```

Sadly this seems to no longer work with version 4.x. For version 4.x i've created a pull request to add a new method to the `Router` to expose the recognize function.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15826

Another side note. it makes sense to also handle errors of the promise (either of the recognize or the new router method), by adding  `.catch((rej) => { // some code if it fails to resolve route })`. It can happen that it fails to resolve the url->routestatesnapshot. Either because the url is wrong or you use async routes via `LoadChildren` and the routes are not yet loaded. Breadcrumbs work great using this even with async routes. If you use it to check permissions, for example via a directive, you need to watch out if you use async routes.

Answer (score 3):

There is another way to get the data config for routes.  It involves knowing what the `key` property in the data object.

In your component you can get the data for that exact route with

```
this.route.snapshot.data['key']
```

You could get the parent's data with

```
this.route.snapshot.parent.data['key']
```

Or even the grandparent's data with

```
this.route.snapshot.parent.parent.data['key']
```

Since you are using different keys on all your routes, that makes it more difficult.  In that case, you'd need to get a list of the keys and iterate over that:

```
let keys = Object.keys(this.route.snapshot.data);
keys.map(x => {
    console.log('key', x);
    console.log('data', this.route.snapshot.data[x]);
}
```

Also, if you know your url segments you can even match on that to get the config for a particular path:

```
let configForRoute = this.router.config.find(x => x.path === this. route.snapshot.url.toString())

let dataForSegment = this.router.config.find(x => x.path === 'somePath').data['key']
```

A crude solution to get all the data you need would look something like this:

```
obj = {};
getData(routeData){
  let keys = Object.keys(routeData);
  keys.map(x => this.obj[x] = routeData[x])
}

this.getData(this.route.snapshot.parent.parent.data);
this.getData(this.route.snapshot.parent.data);
this.getData(this.route.snapshot.data);
console.log(obj);
```

Hopefully this helps get you on the right track to getting the data you need.

**EDIT**

I may have misunderstood the original question.

Since the addition of:

> Why would I need that? Imagine I have a 50% of the URLs protected by
>   some guard (e.g. only logged in users could go there) and other 50% is
>   not protected (displayed for everybody). So, on the navigation menu
>   level (outside of the router-outlet) I want to display only the links
>   which are relevant for the current user, so I need to know which
>   routes are protected by the guard. Guards / data / whatever is just a
>   particular case of the problem.

The way I solved this problem of hiding links either unauthenticated users could see or hiding links unauthorized users could see is to create a function on my authentication service that can either check whether a user is authenticated or authorized. It is the same function that is also used by my guards on my routes.

For example, I may have a `CheckPermissions` guard on my routes with the route data `data: { permissions:[permission1, permission2] }`  Behind the scenes this guard uses a function on the auth service to check whether the user has permission using the listed permissions in the data field.  I can also use that same function from the auth service to hide links in my main menu with `*ngIf="authSvc.CheckPermission(permission1)` etc.  This way I'm not having to duplicate the logic anywhere.  Ultimately the API endpoints should be protected server side as well.

As for being able to give the router a url and get back the route that it matches without navigating to it, I can't find a documented way to do that.  Hope this is at least a little bit of help.

Comment: this is true, it works if you just need to get the data of the currently activated route. My problem is that I have only a URL which has nothing to do with the current route; I don't want to activate the URL but I want to know of what configuration will be taking place if I would activate this URL

Comment: added an example to the question in order to clarify this

Comment: Your solution in edit is exactly what I want to avoid. I don't want to care of the routes permissions and the links permissions separately. Although you reuse the function you are still duplicating permissions so you need to remember to change it in two places. I want the menu to understand automatically which link is forbidden.

Comment: Right.  That's why permissions get synced between frontend and backend.    Or you create an exported constant so there aren't any 'magic' strings.

Comment: If you find a better solution, please post it here as an answer.

Comment: Syncing the permissions is quite a task as well. If the backend is just a RESTful API it's permissions usually have nothing to do with the views and pages on the frontend. Anyway, thank you for sharing your experience, +1